# TextView above ImageView with dynamic height

Tags: android, android-layout, uiimageview, textview

I have a ScrollView with some elements.
My problem is that i can't set textview's above ImageView's with dynamical height.

I have 3 ImageView with different height, they can be visible or gone.
Above them i need to put text with background color, this text need to be at the bottom part of the ImageView
[image: ImageView]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/third_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/third_picture"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="example text">
</TextView>
```

I tried a lot, but my View was always broken.
Please help, i need some proffesional advise.

Comment: You can try this- set layout background with any image of your choice....and put textview normally...no imageview needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in textview:

```
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/pic"
```

This will align the baseline of textview with basline of imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can set your picture as a background for a layout (e.g linear layout ) rather than using an ImageView and then put the textview inside it and place it where ever you want.

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:background="your picture" >

             <!-- align it to the bottom -->
             <TextView

              />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can it scale to cropCenter? if no - it's not what i need